# SLES 9 KDE - Bash script to delete panel icon from desktop?

Tags: sles, icons

We have several SLES 9 servers with KDE desktops.  We need to remove a couple of the icons that are in the panel on the bottom left of the desktop next to the "Start" button.

I'd like to push out a little bash script to delete them but I can't find them.  They don't seem to be in the ~/.kde directory or anywhere else I've looked.  Any idea where these little suckers are kept?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop configuration can also be under `~/.local`.  That said, a better way to do this is not removing files, but using `dcop` (for KDE3) or `qdbus` (KDE4) to tell KDE to remove it.  (This if the user is logged in, of course; in that case, simply removing the file may not work because KDE will rewrite it.)

Comment: I couldn't run dcop or qdbus, but I did eventually find the location.  ~/.kde/share/apps/kicker.  Thanks!